# What did the animals eat before Adam prayed for the trees to grow?

Tags: tanach, parashat-bereishit

We learn in chullin 60b that the trees and herbage only began to sprout on the third day and that they only grew fully when Adam prayed for the rain (Genesis 2:5). If none of the plant life grew yet, what did the animals eat until Adam prayed for the rain?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: The animals were created on the same day as Adam, presumably on the same day that he prayed and it rained. So it wasn’t that long

Comment: What about the fish and birds though?

Comment: The two reasons given for why there was no plant-life in Scripture are 1) No rain yet. 2) No man to work field. Neither of these seem to apply under water, so presumably all sea life is out of the question. Regarding birds, do you know of any species that can't survive more than 24 or so hours without food?

Comment: Also, in your very question you acknowledge how foliage began sprouting. Shouldn't that technically be enough to survive on? 
TBH though, for those who want to impose millions of years into the length of each day of creation (which I probably wouldn't agree with personally except for the first few days when there was no sun to base each day's duration off of), according to that line of thought you indeed have a good question. Maybe edit your question to include that point.